# What's the correct syntax to use Processing gdalogr:merge from python?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing

I am using `gdalogr:merge`in Python console in order to merge to rasters (.tif) But I don't really understand the first parameter, where I have to put two variables.

I get the following error:

> Unable to execute algorithm
> Wrong parameter value: ras1; ras2
>
> None

```
import processing   
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

ras1 =QgsRasterLayer("H:/pyQGIS/DATA_U6/mdt_483.tif","MDT483")
ras2 = QgsRasterLayer("H:/pyQGIS/DATA_U6/mdt_508.tif", "MDT508")

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([ras1])
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([ras2])

merj = processing.runalg("gdalogr:merge",'ras1; ras2', False, False, 4,"H:/pyQGIS/DATA_U6/mdt_mosaico.tif")
print(repr(merj))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm @GermánCarrillo's solution also worked for me. If you want to use `ras1` and `ras2` as input parameters then you can try the following:

```
import processing

ras1 = "H:/pyQGIS/DATA_U6/mdt_483.tif"
ras2 = "H:/pyQGIS/DATA_U6/mdt_508.tif"

merj = processing.runalg("gdalogr:merge", ras1 + ";" + ras2, False, False, 4,"H:/pyQGIS/DATA_U6/mdt_mosaico.tif")
```

Answer (score 3):

The algorithm expects (in the first argument) the input raster paths using a semicolon as separator. Don't add any blank space after the semicolon.

Your script could be just 2 lines long now:

```
import processing

merj = processing.runalg('gdalogr:merge','H:/pyQGIS/DATA_U6/mdt_483.tif;H:/pyQGIS/DATA_U6/mdt_508.tif', False, False, 4,'H:/pyQGIS/DATA_U6/mdt_mosaico.tif')
```

It should do the trick. I've tested it with Processing versions 2.10.3 and 2.12.2 on QGIS 2.14.1 (Essen).

Comment: This is not working, that is why It is so extrange, according to the documentation, this should work . My QGIS version  is 2.14 (Essen)

Comment: What version of Processing are you using? On my GNU/Linux machine, using QGIS 2.14.1 and Processing 2.10.3, it worked!

Comment: It is 2.14 (Essen),The version of my Processing is 2.12.2. I tried to change spaces from the ";" but still get nothing..The same error

Comment: Just copy & paste the line I included in my answer. No need to change anything else. I'll have a look with Processing 2.12.2